# Unable to make web socket connection in Selenium opened googleChrome browser

Tags: selenium

Below is the test page to check the web socket connection, I am opening below page in selenium with (*googlechrome), i am unable to connect to the web sockets.

> > http://websocket.org/echo.html

However in normal googlechrome browser we are able to connect to the web socket.

What is the difference? appreciate your quick help..

~Ashok

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to connect the web socket with other browser? I had the similar problem before but I was using Firefox, it turned out that the proxy setting wasn't get pass on to the firefox profile which selenium use.